# Why does ''cat "${1:-/dev/stdin} | ... &>/dev/null'' work in bash but not dash?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection, dash

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# reads stdin/file and copies it to clipboard
# clears it after 30s
#
cat "${1:-/dev/stdin}" | timeout 30 xclip -i -selection clipboard -r -verbose &>/dev/null &
```

I can see that only stdin does not work (with bash it works on stdin/file).
P.S. verbose is used to make xclip not daemonize.

Comment: That won't work with `/dev/stdin` even with bash. Since you're running with the pipeline put in the background (terminated with `&`) `cat /dev/stdin` will either have its stdin redirected from `/dev/null` (when running in a script) or will be stopped by a `SIGTTIN` signal (when running in an interactive shell).

Comment: you sure about the second? because it works (bash) in my terminal `echo 123 | script`.  Is there anyway I can do what I want to do?

Comment: Look at end of the pipeline in your Q. There's a `&` at the end -- the shell won't treat it as decoration ;-)

Comment: of course not but whole script will work in the foreground (because of -verbose but -verbose is needed to make timeout work)

Comment: Try this in your script: `exec 3<"${1:-/dev/stdin}"; cat <&3 | ... &`.

Comment: It works! Thank you, I think you should make your comment an answer. Can I ask you how it works? I mean there is exec I thought nothing after it gets executed

Comment: `exec 3<foo 7>bar 2>&1` without a command just performs the redirections in the shell it's called from, without executing anything.

Comment: you were right that that works in `bash`  -- yet another nasty incompatibility to be aware of. See the answer for some details. But the `exec` workaround from my comment works fine, even in `bash`.

Comment: Do not edit your accepted answer into the question itself. Instead, mark your question as answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer you want to accept. If none of the answers are quite on-point, it's entirely acceptable to add your own; even then, an answer should be added *as an answer* using the "Add An Answer" button, not edited into the question; and [any answer in the question should be edited out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit).

Comment: I've moved the answer from the Question into mosvy's Answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[this answer is about asynchronous pipelines in scripts; for the deprecated `&>` bash operator and why you should always use `>output 2>&1` instead, refer to [obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)]

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> cat "${1:-/dev/stdin}" | ... &
> ```

Here you have a pipeline running asynchronously (because terminated by `&`), started from a script, ie is from a shell with the job control disabled.

According to the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03_02):

> `command1 & [command2 & ... ]`
>
> The standard input for an asynchronous list, before any explicit
>      redirections are performed, shall be considered to be assigned to a file that has the same properties as `/dev/null`.

The problem is that `dash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `yash`, etc intepret "asynchronous list" as any command, including a pipeline, and will redirect the stdin of the first command from `/dev/null`:

```
$ echo foo | dash -c 'cat | tr fo FO & echo DONE'
DONE
$ echo | dash -c 'readlink /proc/self/fd/0 | cat & echo DONE'
DONE
/dev/null
```

But `bash` will only interpret it as "simple command" and will only redirect its stdin from `/dev/null` when it's *not* part of a pipeline:

```
$ echo foo | bash -c 'cat | tr fo FO & echo DONE'
DONE
FOO
$ echo | bash -c 'readlink /proc/self/fd/0 | cat & echo DONE'
DONE
pipe:[69872]
$ echo | bash -c 'readlink /proc/self/fd/0 & echo DONE'
DONE
/dev/null
$ bash -c 'cat | tr a A & echo DONE'
DONE
cat: -: Input/output error
```

`zsh` will only redirect it from `/dev/null` when the original stdin is a tty, not when it's other kind of file:

```
$ zsh -c 'readlink /proc/self/fd/0 &' </dev/tty
/dev/null
$ zsh -c 'readlink /proc/self/fd/0 &' </dev/zero
/dev/zero
```

---

A workaround which works in all shells is to duplicate the stdin into another file descriptor, and redirect the stdin of the first command from it:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec 3<"${1:-/dev/stdin}"
cat <&3 | timeout 30 xclip -i -selection clipboard -verbose -r >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: nitpick: in the POSIX grammar/terminology,  a simple command (like `readlink /proc/self/fd/0`) is a pipeline (with one element) and `readlink /proc/self/fd/0 | cat` a pipeline with two elements. In bash and POSIX shells (but not zsh), a `&` affects an and-or list, not just the last pipeline in the and-or list. See also the current discussion on the austin-group ML about http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1254

Answer (score 10):

`&>` is a bashism, you will have to change it to `>/dev/null 2>&1` for POSIX shells

Comment: Now stdout is suppressed like it should be thank you BUT stdin is still not working ($1 works).  Also I had to use `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 7):

`dash` positioned as POSIX standard. POSIX specified only `[n]>` redirection. But `bash` introduces many own features. `&>` is one of them and means output descriptors (`stderr` and `stdout`).

You should read article about [bash and dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) compatibility.

Maybe you get helpful [checkbashisms](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/checkbashisms.1.html) utility which can helps to find `bash`-specific instructions in your scripts.

Comment: `&>` is *only* stdout and stderr, not "all" file descriptors. (It's also [considered obsolescent](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) and not suggested for use, even in bash).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank's for correction. I've just fixed it in the own answer!